# Express Nodejs Http To Https Forwarding Only Happens After Second Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, deployment, web-deployment

I've been trying for a while to fix this issue and can't seem to be able to make it work. I have a site that only works with https, and I want all requests that come to the domain via http to be forwarded to the https version of the site. Here is a snippet from my express server file (when I run it in production I pass in the -p flag so in this case it will enter the first if statement):

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('../client'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '../client/index.html');
});

if (process.argv.indexOf("-p") != -1) {

    http.createServer((req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(301, { Location: `https://gameof.ninja` })
        res.end()
    }).listen(80);

    const options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/gameof.ninja/privkey.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/gameof.ninja/fullchain.pem')
    };

    server = https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(200)
        res.end('Works!')
    }).listen(443);

    wss = new WebSocket.Server({server: server});
    console.log('listening prod.')

} else {

    server = http.createServer(app).listen(8889);
    wss = new WebSocket.Server({server: server});
    console.log('listening dev.')
}
```

The domain for my webapp is "gameof.ninja", but the problem though now is that when I initially go to "http://gameof.ninja" it doesn't automatically forward to the https version. Instead, it just times out and does nothing. Strangely though, the second time I try to request the http version of the site it does correctly forward to "https://gameof.ninja". I've also tried to use the libraries "express-force-ssl" and "express-http-to-https" but with no success. Please help me to have it immediately forward to https the very first time I enter the http version in the address bar. Thanks!

Comment: What's the `app.use()` and `app.get()` code doing here?  Is there yet another server in this same file?  On what port is it operating?

Comment: 1) It's standard express.js code 2) no, just these. 3) http on 8889 for dev, http on 80 and https on 443 for prod.